# Filter a Query Set

Tags: filter, view, django-queryset

The following view works great.  I pass in student_id and I get a queryset of headers and attendance days related to that student_id.  My challenge is that I cannot figure out how to filter my attendance_days queryset by a specific date or date range.

I have tried variations of:

```
attendance_days = student.zzabsentdetail_set.order_by('-absent_date').filter('absent_date' is between '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-26')
```

or

```
attendance_days = student.zzabsentdetail_set.order_by('-absent_date').filter('absent_date' > '2021-02-01')
```

I would like to filter my zzabsent_detail queryset by absent date on that line if possible.

Here is my view:

```
def absent_detail(request, student_id):
    """Show student & attendance info"""
    student = Student.objects.get(id=student_id)
    header = student.zzheader_set.order_by('id')
    attendance_days = student.zzabsentdetail_set.order_by('-absent_date')
    context = {'student': student, 'header': header, 'attendance_days': 
attendance_days}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/absent_detail_99.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [**`__range`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
attendance_days = student.zzabsentdetail_set.filter(
    absent_date__range=('2021-02-01', '2021-02-26')
).order_by('-absent_date')
```

here the two bounds are *inclusive*, so items on February 1st, or February 26th will be included as well.

or you can work with the [**`__gt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) to express that the value should be greater than a given value:

```
attendance_days = student.zzabsentdetail_set.filter(
    absent_date__gt='2021-02-01'
).order_by('-absent_date')
```

for the last 10 days, you can work with a `date` object instead of a string, so:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

from_dt = now().date()-timedelta(days=10)

attendance_days = student.zzabsentdetail_set.filter(
    absent_date__gt=from_dt
).order_by('-absent_date')
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Much gratitude!  Can I ask, how would I apply same concept to filtering for absences within the last 10 days of the current date?

Comment: @ScottNorman: see edit. You perhaps want to replace `__gt` with `__gte` depending on whether it should be greater than, or *greater than or equal*.